# Collatz Sequence. (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started the book ["Automate The Boring Stuff" by Al Sweigart](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/).

At the end of Chapter 3, the author suggests creating a Collatz Sequence in Python as a practice exercise. (the practice exercise suggests I use a the print function and return statement)

When I use a `print()` function in my code, it works great and I get all the evaluated values I want to see on the screen:

```
print("This is The Collatz Sequence")
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))


def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            print(n)
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            print(n)


collatz(user)
```

**Question:**
How come when I want to use the `return` statement, the `while` loop only runs once?

For example, passing the integer 3 into my function with the `return` statement only gives me the `return` value of 3 and 10:

```
print("This is The Collatz Sequence")
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))


def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            return n
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            return n


result = collatz(user)
print(result)
```

Comment: Because return exits your function.

Answer (score 3):

`return` exits the function and, therefore terminates your `while` loop.

Perhaps you meant to use `yield` instead:

```
print("This is The Collatz Sequence")
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            yield(n)
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            yield(n)

print(list(collatz(user)))
```

Output:

```
This is The Collatz Sequence
Enter a number: 3
3
[10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

[Yield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/298607) is logically similar to a `return` but the function is not terminated until a defined `return` or the end of the function is reached. When the [yield statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) is executed, the generator function is suspended and the value of the [yield expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-yield_expression) is returned to the caller. Once the caller finishes (and assumably uses the value that was sent) execution returns to the generator function right after the `yield` statement.

Comment: Return doesn't just exit the loop, it exits the function!

Comment: True. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe you need add some explanation that tells OP *How does `yield` work* :)

Comment: I see that now.  Thank you.  Is it possible to stay in the function with a return statement?

Comment: @R2DPoop: Yes -- use `yield`.

Comment: @dawg Ok, it's starting to make sense to me.  Thank you and everyone else for helping in answering my question.  Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you don't re-feed the new value back into your equation. Try separating your while loop from the collatz module. I have an example of this below:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number + 1

chosenInt = int(input('Enter an integer greater than 1: '))

print(chosenInt)

while chosenInt != 1:
    chosenInt = collatz(chosenInt)
    print(chosenInt)
```